# Unable to get context from Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to call a fragment method from an activity but I am getting a null pointer exception when setting the adapter context with `getActivity()` in that method:

**Fragment Method**

```
public void fragmentMethod() {
            String[] names = new String[]{"name1", "name2", "name3"};
            String[] values = new String[]{value1, value2, value3};
            adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), names, values);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] names;
    private final String[] values;

    public MyArrayAdapter (Context context, String[] names, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
    }

}
```

**Call to Fragment Method from Activity**

```
public void activityMethod() {
    FragmentName  test= new FragmentName();
    test.fragmentMethod();
}
```

I have tried many different things and I'm at a loss here...if I am fundamentally wrong in what I am trying to do, please let me know as I am a novice. Thank you!

**Edit: Stack Trace**

(`Inventory` is the Fragment class)

This is after clicking an imageview which calls `activityMethod()`

```
06-04 19:55:17.976    1147-1147/company.com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
        at company.com.myapp.MyArrayAdapter.<init>(MyArrayAdapter.java:18)
        at company.com.myapp.Inventory.createList(Inventory.java:105)
        at company.com.myapp.MainActivity.newDay(MainActivity.java:177)
        at company.com.myapp.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:91)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?  From where is `activityMethod()` called?  Is the fragment's `onAttach()` method called before `fragmentMethod()`?

Comment: @pathfinderelite I have `activityMethod()` being called in the activity after `onCreate()`. Editing with stack trace. Very new to debugging, so I cannot answer if `onAttach()` is called yet...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if I am fundamentally wrong in what I am trying to do, please let me know as I am a novice

You cannot call `getActivity()` and get a response until the fragment is attached to an activity. In the case of a dynamic fragment — one you are creating directly via the constructor — this will be sometime after you `commit()` a `FragmentTransaction` that will put this fragment in a `FragmentManager`.

Moreover, there is no point in setting up your adapter until the `ListView` is ready.

So, simply move your `fragmentMethod()` code into [an `onViewCreated()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated(android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle)) on your fragment. This will be called at a point in time when both the fragment is attached to the activity *and* the `ListView` is ready to receive your adapter.

Comment: I originally had the `fragmentMethod()` code in `onApplicationCreated()` which worked fine (but will move to `onViewCreated()`) however, I had to move it to the custom method since I needed to call it from the activity. How would I call a part of code in one of those methods, from the activity? Should I look into setting up Interfaces? Thanks!

Comment: @zngb: Beyond the `null` `getActivity()` problem, you can't call `setListAdapter()` until after the `ListView` is created, and that won't be until `onCreateView()` completes. If you are trying to pass data into the fragment, use the factory pattern (static `newInstance()` method) and the arguments `Bundle`, so you retain the data across configuration changes and such. If none of that is acceptable, you'll just need to implement the spaghetti code to deal with the cases where `getActivity()` does and does not work, caching information if needed until the fragment is attached.

Answer (score 0):

From the code above, your fragment didn't associate to any activity. So `getActivity()` call will return null until you attach your fragment to activity.

```
private void activityMethod() {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(fragment, "myfragment").commit();
    fragment.fragmentMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do that inside `onActivityCreated()` or inside `onAttach()`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding this: I originally had the `fragmentMethod()` code in `onApplicationCreated()` which worked fine (but will move to `onViewCreated()`) however, I had to move it to the custom method since I needed to call it from the activity. How would I call a part of code in one of those methods, from the activity? Should I look into setting up Interfaces? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, to call a Fragment method from an Activity you should use an interface